# Trouble with speed and vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working on adding bullets to my game.  Right now I can shoot bullets in the direction that I would like from a ship by getting the ship's angle:

```
int speed = 5;
int dx = -(cos(degreesToRadians(ship.angle)) * speed); // rate of change in the x direction
int dy = -(sin(degreesToRadians(ship.angle)) * speed); // rate of change in the y direction

bulletPosition.addX(dx); // addX(dx) is simply bulletPosition.x += dx
bulletPosition.addY(dy);
```

The ship is pretty much the exact same thing, except I use the += operator:

```
int dx += -(cos(degreesToRadians(angle)) * 0.15)
int dy += -(sin(degreesToRadians(angle)) * 0.15);

shipPosition.addX(dx);
shipPosition.addY(dy);
```

I would like to be able to add the ship's velocity to the bullet's velocity, but I'm a little confused as to how should get the speed from the ship's vector.  I thought that adding the ship's `dx` to the bullet's `dx` like `int dx = -(cos(degreesToRadians(ship.angle)) * speed * dx)` would work because I'm adding the rate of change of the ship to the rate of change of the bullet, but that doesn't work.  So here's the final question: How can I get the speed of my ship and apply it to my bullet's speed?

Thanks in advance for all help :)

Comment: It's a lot easier if you use vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do want to add the ship's `dx`/`dy` to the bullet's `dx`/`dy`, but you want addition, not multiplication.

```
bulletDx = -(cos(degreesToRadians(bulletHeading)) * speed) + shipDx;
```